# Cual es la diferencia entre este ciclo for: for(auto i: vector) y un ciclo for de la forma for(int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)

Tags: c++, bucle-for, vectores

Estaba viendo un video de un código para un programa en C++ que cuenta los números primos de un numero inicial a uno final y los guarda en un vector, pero hay un punto donde usan el ciclo for del titulo para mostrar los números dentro del vector, pero es la primera vez que lo veo.

Me gustaría saber para que sirve independientemente del contexto en el que se use (por eso no coloco ningún tipo de código) y cual es la diferencia con el otro tipo de ciclo for que coloque.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: De forma simple, es mejor el for tradicional cuando quieres o necesitas la posición de cada elemento. Si solo quieres recorrer el arreglo, es mejor el otro ya que te olvidas de una variable `i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For clásico:

```
for (int i=0; i<vector.size(); i++)
```

Este es el bucle `for` que lleva con nosotros desde los inicios de C++. De hecho es una de las características heredadas de C.

Si bien este bucle es bastante sencillo de implementar presenta algunos inconvenientes:

- Necesidad de iterar expresamente `i`
- En cada iteración se está invocando el método `size()`

Este bucle se podría mejorar de la siguiente forma:

```
for (int i=0, end=vector.size(); i<end; i++)
```

Ahora ya no se invoca el método `size()` en cada iteración pero a cambio hemos conseguido un bucle un poco más engorroso y feo. Además de que tenemos una variable `end` que tenemos que evitar modificar a toda costa.

Para simplificar un poco este código, el estándar C++11 nos ofreció el `for` basado en rangos:

```
for(auto item : vector)
```

Esta forma del bucle es mucho más legible y elimina los problemas asociados a la forma anterior:

- No tenemos que preocuparnos de incrementar ninguna variable ni iterador
- No se está invocando el método `size` en cada iteración
- No tenemos que gestionar el fin de la iteración

**¿Pero entonces el primer `for` ya no sirve para nada?**

Ni mucho menos. No hay que olvidar que el `for` basado en rangos necesita una colección sobre la que iterar. Así, si no tenemos una colección como tal no podremos utilizar, al menos en principio, este nuevo `for`:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) // <<--- No hay colección
```

Además, el `for` basado en rangos no tiene niguna flexibilidad a la hora de determinar los desplazamientos a través de la colección. Si necesitamos iterar de una forma no convencional (indices pares, intercalar decrementos, ...) no podremos usar el `for` basado en rangos

```
for (int i=0; i<vector.size(); i+=2)
```

Otro caso que no se puede abordar con el `for` basado en rangos lo encontramos cuando queremos eliminar elementos de la colección.

En algunos contenedores el método `erase` te devuelve un iterador al siguiente elemento de la colección.

Dado que el `for` basado en rangos no te deja interactuar con el proceso de iteración, no lo puedes utilizar en este caso.

```
for (auto it=vector.begin(); it!=vector.end(); /* sin incremento */)
{
    if (*it % 2 == 0) // Eliminamos los elementos pares
        it = vector.erase(it);
    else
        it++;
}
```

**Adaptadores para el for basado en rangos**

Realmente te he engañado a medias. Hay casos que se pueden tratar con el `for` basado en rangos pero para ello necesitamos adaptar nuestra colección.

Por ejemplo, para iterar en reversa podemos hacer lo [siguiente](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lXDlK2JCxqOiw5zx)

```
std::vector<int> datos = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

class reverse
{
public:
    reverse(std::vector<int> & datos)
        : datos{datos}
    { }

    auto begin()
    { return datos.rbegin(); }

    auto end()
    { return datos.rend(); }

private:
    std::vector<int> & datos;
};

for (int item : reverse(datos))
{ std::cout << item; }
```

En este caso también existe un adaptador ya hecho en [BOOST](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/reversed.html). El ejemplo es solo para fines didácticos.

Como ves, para usar el `for` basado en rangos en escenarios particulares tenemos que ser capaces de crear el adaptador correspondiente

Comment: Cabe mencionar que al declarar la variable de iteración con `auto`, se produce una copia. Si quieres una referencia tienes que hacerlo explícitamente con `auto&` o `auto&&`.

Comment: Gracias a ambos. 

Mateo me brindo un resumen muy bueno y entendible de para que sirve cada uno, así como aclararme lo del auto (de lo cual también me surgía un poco de duda). 

Por tu parte eferion, tu respuesta es más extensa pero igualmente entendible fácilmente, brindando ejemplos lo cual hace la explicación aun más valiosa.